# Lookup of JMS Connection Factory Pool on Glassfish cluster fails

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, jndi

I have an application that works on a standalone domain but fails in the cluster setup.

In my application I have a JCA Resource Adapter that needs to send a message over a JMS Message on a specific situation in the EIS, so in the Connection Implementation after the event I call `getJMSConnectionFactory`.

```
private Object lookup(String what) {
    try {
        // needs no environment
        Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        return jndiContext.lookup(what);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        throw MyProjectException.getInstance("lookup of " + what + " failed.", ex);
    }
}

public ConnectionFactory getJMSConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    return (ConnectionFactory)lookup("java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory");
}
```

I also lookup the Destination that way and send the JMS message afterwards. Now that works as expected when I deploy to a single domain, but when I try to do that in a clustered setup, I get this exception (relevant details below):

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
Caused by: myclasspath.MyProjectException: sayHelloyOverJMS
Caused by: myclasspath.MyProjectException: lookup of java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory failed.
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/__defaultConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : jms/__defaultConnectionFactory [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}]]]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/__defaultConnectionFactory' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : jms/__defaultConnectionFactory [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}]]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : jms/__defaultConnectionFactory [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}]
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms]
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms
```

I think the relevant details are:

```
Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool'.
```

That seems to find '__SYSTEM/pools' but then not 'jms'. I did look into the GUI of Glassfish to the configuration of the connection pool 
`jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool`, but I did not find any information about 'targets' there, so I assume it should be available in the whole domain, including clusters. The Resources Tab of the cluster configuration does not list the connection pool (or any other '__SYSTEM' entries for that matter).

When I ask glassfish what JNDI Resources are available:

```
$ asadmin list-jms-resources cluster_name
jms/DataFlowClusterCommunicationTopic
jms/__defaultConnectionFactory
Command list-jms-resources executed successfully.

$ asadmin list-jms-resources domain-1-instance
remote failure: The list-jms-resources command is not allowed on target domain-1-instance because it is part of cluster cluster_name
Command list-jms-resources failed.

$ asadmin list-jms-resources domain
jms/DataFlowClusterCommunicationTopic
jms/__defaultConnectionFactory
Command list-jms-resources executed successfully.
```

So, as far as I understood it, the `jms/__defaultConnectionFactory` name is present, and should be found in the clustered setup as much as the domain setup.

Environment:

- AS: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 (build 1)
- Java:

  - openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2-b14)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
- OS: Linux fuchs-linux-pc 4.7.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.7.8-1 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Build with maven 3

Comment: Have you done any progress on this issue ?, i'm having the same one

Comment: @karelss Unfortunately not and by now I don't have the issue myself anymore (am not on the project anymore). We had the opportunity to switch to a different AS and did so. There it worked, but that vague feeling of problems waiting to happen stayed.

Comment: @karelss If you upvote this question it gets pushed up in the frontpage. If you instead choose to ask a new question please leave a link so one can eventually be closed as duplicate.

Comment: After doing a little research i found a few bugs reported on glassfish jira related to this issue, like https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21656 or https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21655, i'm going to wait to check if this problem is fixed on versión 5.0.

Comment: @karelss Both issues are already closed. Did you try a version 4.1.2 already?

Comment: Well, after a few test on 4.1.0, i found a work around, the issue occurs with the embebed jms provider. After switching to REMOTE i 've been able to use correctly the jms apis, this article shows how to use a remote jms resources http://blog.jankowalski.pl/send-jms-msg-to-remote-server-with-glassfish.html

Comment: @karelss Could you post an answer to this question, then? Comments are no good for answers and you have just solved a problem that most likely about a hundred people had since it was asked :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this post because I suffer the same issue with glassfish version 4.0 and 4.1.1 when i tried to move my project from standalone setup into a cluster setup.

After doing a few test I was able to discover a few issues accepted by glassfish team related with jms systems only in cluster mode as far as I was able to test, changing from Embedded openmq setup to [remote](http://blog.jankowalski.pl/send-jms-msg-to-remote-server-with-glassfish.html) or local one FIX the issue, and the system works well in cluster.

This behaviour makes me think that the issue is related with the JNDI Tree with Embedded openMQ setup